# Center a DIV inside a HMTL Body

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have just started learning CSS, I ran into this problem. Please excuse me if its too silly to ask.

I want to center a DIV inside the body tag. I tired to use flexbox for this but somehow its coming in the center of the screen.

Here is the code.

```
 <html lang="en">
    <body>
    <style type="text/css">
    
        body
        {
            background: #6CB3A9;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }
        .main
        {
            width:300px;
            height:300px;
            background:white;
        }
    
    </style>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="white-bottom"></div>
            <div class="red-top"></div>
            <div class="yellow-center"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It's already centered! if you wanna see it in the middle of the screen vertically you have to give your body a specific height `height: 100vh;` in body style

Answer (score -1):

No need for `align-items: center;` if you're using `display: flex;`:

Note: I set a `height` for the body to demonstrate that it sits horizontally in the center of the `body` tag.

```html
 <html lang="en">
    <body>
    <style type="text/css">
    
        body
        {
            background: #6CB3A9;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            // align-items: center;
            height: 500px;
            border: 1px solid grey
        }
        .main
        {
            width:300px;
            height:300px;
            background:white;
        }
    
    </style>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="white-bottom"></div>
            <div class="red-top"></div>
            <div class="yellow-center"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: If this does not satisfy your question, could I/we get a little more clarification on what is needed